# Syntax for bootstrap estimates from ttest command

Tags: stata, statistics-bootstrap

I am attempting to demonstrated characteristics of various tests for small samples of data. I would like to demonstrate the performance of the t-test, t-test with bootstrap estimation and the ranksum test. I am interested in obtaining the p-value for each test on multiple sets of data using `simulate`. However, I cannot obtain t-test estimates using the `bootstrap` prefix and `ttest` command.

The data is generated by:

```
clear
set obs 60
gen level = abs(rnormal(0,1))
gen group = "A"
replace group = "B" if [_n] >30

bootstrap, reps(100): ttest level, by(group)
bootstrap _b, reps(100): ttest level, by(group)
bootstrap boot_p = e(p), reps(100): ttest level, by(group)
```

The errors for each of the procedures in order are:

1. > expression list required
2. > invalid expression: _b
3. > 'e(p)' evaluated to missing in full sample

These results are not consistent with the documentation for the `bootstrap` prefix. Is there some problem with specification of e or r class objects and `ttest` ?

Edit:

Understanding now that r-class is the correct group of scalars, I still do not generate a variable 'p' given the code provided in the solution. Additionally:

```
clear
set more off

set obs 60

gen level = abs(rnormal(0,1))
gen group = "A"
replace group = "B" if [_n] >30

bootstrap p=r(p), reps(100): ttest level, by(group)
    display r(p)
```

does not return the p-value.

Comment: `return list` after `bootstrap` does not contain `r(p)`,\will show you that `r(p)` is not returned by `bootstrap`, so your last command will produce an error.

Answer (score 2):

`ttest` is an *r-class* command and stores its reults in `r()`. You seem to expect for it to save results in `e()`, like an *e-class* command. The norm is that the latter kind fit models; `ttest` is not in this category.

The two-sided *p-value* is stored in `r(p)`, as indicated in `help ttest`:

```
clear
set more off

set obs 60

gen level = abs(rnormal(0,1))
gen group = "A"
replace group = "B" if [_n] >30

bootstrap p=r(p), reps(100): ttest level, by(group)
```

Comment: This solution is not working as noted above in the edited query.

Comment: `bootstrap` has its own help file and you have easy access to it with `help bootstrap`. There you can find that the bootstrap result is in `e(b)`. Run `matrix list e(b)` to display it. Regarding your desire to create a variable, if you want intermediate results check the `saving()` option for `bootstrap`. If you want to save the final result, you now know how to access it. See `help postfile` on saving results to a Stata dataset. My recommendation is to make a better use of the `help files` and Stata manuals. (You can make any answer irrelevant, modifying your question just enough.)